# why Pivot is giving error as 'Incorrect syntax near '4721'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like below -

```
[ID]    [PID]
1       4721
2       25
3       4721
```

And I create a Pivot using the below mentioned Query -

```
select id,pid
from #a
pivot(sum(id) for pid in(4721,25)) as pvt
```

but I am getting error in the above code as - 
Incorrect syntax near '4721'. I am not able to figure out why. Can you tell me where I am missing. I want the resultant table like -

```
[4721]  [25]
4,       2
```

Comment: Try `in([4721],[25]))`... see how [all examples in the documentation that have numeric output column names surround them with square brackets](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks..It such a small thing and did not strike my mind..I appreciate your efforts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using `[`,`]` can solve it

```
select id,pid
from #a
pivot(sum(id) for pid in([4721],[25])) as pvt
```

> The syntax for PIVOT:

```
PIVOT 
( 
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>) 
FOR 
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>] 
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column], 
    ... [last pivoted column]) 
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
```